# JavaFX Dialog hides the fullscreen stage on Ubuntu 14.10 (Utopic Unicorn)

Tags: java, ubuntu, javafx, dialog

I'm using Dialog that is packed with Java 8u40 (replaces ControlsFX Dialogs) to create a dialog window on top of a fullscreen stage. The OS I'm working on is Ubuntu 14.10, and I'm running the application from Eclipse.

When the dialog appears, the primary stage is hidden. The actual background behind the dialog is my desktop. Obviously, I'd like to retain the primary JavaFX stage as background of the dialog. In that case, the dialog is placed on top of the primary stage. On Mac OSX 10.10 Yosemite and Windows 8.1, this is working properly. On an older version of Ubuntu (14.04 Trusty), the problem also exists. When the primaryStage is **not** in fullscreen, the dialogs are shown on top of the primarystage, and the primarystage is not hidden (so then it works like it should).

Does anyone recognize this problem? I've already tried setting the owner of the dialog to `null` and to `primaryStage.getOwner()`, as mentioned in this question [JavaFX popup hidden when stage is in fullscreen mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27258535/javafx-popup-hidden-when-stage-is-in-fullscreen-mode):

```
Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
alert.initOwner(Main.primaryStage.getOwner());
alert.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have the same problem. Alert or javaFX new Stage created in code (without a fxml) are both showing the ubuntu dock and menu like leaving the fullscreen mode. After closing the alert or the new stage on top, the primaryStage is in fullscreen mode again. While it works on OSX Yosemite and Windows8.1
Did you found any solution or workaround to this? (Or anyone else?) Help appreciated. (ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Java 1.8.0_60-b27)

Comment: I'm still having this problem on Ubuntu 16.04 and Java 10.0.2 Anyone know if this was fixed somehow?

Comment: We didn't fix it unfortunately. We had to move to a different OS (Fedora) for other reasons, and the issue wasn't present there.